# Regular Expression to Match OData Query

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
(absolute_performance eq 12.2M)
```

The only variance I may have in this string is that `eq` may be replaced by `ge` or `le` and 12.2 may be any decimal number or integer.  So it could be 0, 0.1, 23, 12.34 etc.

I have have got the beginnings of a regex for this but don't know the rest.

```
\(absolute_performance\seq|ge|le\s([0-9]+)M\)
```

Later on, I want to extract the number, hence the brackets around it.

What is the rest of it?

**EDIT**

I have got, what I believe, is the answer.  Is it correct though?

```
\(absolute_performance\seq|ge|le\s([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)M\)
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is an improvement based on hwnd's suggestions

```
\(absolute_performance\s(eq|ge|le)\s([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)M\)
```

Comment: what is your end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [**grouping**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) construct to group your alternations. You can write this as:

```
\(absolute_performance\s(?:eq|ge|le)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)M\)
```